# Wodpress: дублирование контента при вложенных рубриках

Tags: wordpress

Вопрос в том, что если я делаю в Wordpress URL из вложенных рубрик (стандартный функционал WP рубрики + записи), например

/category/first/second/third/

то я могу заменить first или second на что угодно, а контент страницы не изменится

/category/first111222/sometext/third/

Возьмем для примера любой популярный сайт и увидем, что даже на таких сайтах эту проблему почему-то не решили.

Контент в рубрике https://mama.ru/articles/category/childhealth/safety/burns/

полностью идентичен https://mama.ru/articles/category/dfgdfgdfg/sfddfg/burns/

А должен выдавать 404! Решения в Сети не нашел...

Comment: Это одна из  древних багофич. Там каноникал. Разработчики ВП уверены что этого достаточно. (но я лично против таких костылей)

Comment: Это не баг, а фича

Comment: @KAGGDesign, задокументированный баг является фичей (с)ЮБ :). Сокращённо - багофича(с)Я.

Answer (score 0):

Подумал и вот какая функция сработает:

```
function error_404_for_cat_url() {
  global $wp_query; // загружаем глобальные данные

 /* Если находимся в категории и правильный URL страницы не совпадает с текущим, вызываем ошибку 404 */
  if( is_category() && !stristr(get_category_link(get_cat_id(single_cat_title('', 0))), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) )
  {
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
    get_template_part( 404 );
    exit();
  }
}

add_action('wp', 'error_404_for_cat_url');
```

Comment: Проще использовать wp_get_canonical_url :)

Comment: @SeVlad нет, wp_get_canonical_url работает корректно для записи, а не рубрики